# google cloud vision の getDescription などのリファレンスはどこにあるのでしょうか？

Tags: php, google-api

php を使って cloud vision を使おうと思っています。
ネット上のサンプルのコードにて、OCRとして動かすことはできました。

そこで使われていた `getDescription` なのですが、このリファレンスを見ようと思いました。
しかし、どこにあるのかわかりません。

[Cloud Vision API ドキュメント リファレンス](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/apis?hl=ja)
この中に「[クライアント ライブラリー PHP](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/latest/vision/visionclient)」がありますが、404エラーになります。

[cloud vision api getDescription で検索](https://cloud.google.com/s/results?hl=ja&q=cloud%20vision%20api%20getDescription%20&doctype=apireference&text=cloud%20vision%20api%20getDescription) をしても、
getDescription が使われたコードが大量にヒットして、リファレンスを見つけられません。

どこかにあるとは思うのですが、ご存知でしたら教えてください。
このメソッド以外の使い方のリファレンスを探しています。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参考にされたサンプルコードとそのサイトのリンクを貼っていただけるとより正確なことが言えると思いますが，おそらく https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php を使っていらっしゃると仮定して回答します

また，CloudVision のクライアントはここです
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/tree/main/Vision

getDescription() で検索するといくつかヒットしますね
https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Agoogleapis%2Fgoogle-cloud-php%20getDescription&type=code

この辺がそれっぽいですかね
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/74f719bdecbc5a874b6a5df1581b7e02c7842c75/Vision/src/V1/Product.php#L166-L176

Comment: ありがとうございます。
Githubの方にあるとは考えていませんでした。